# Vue JS. Toggle child component modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Parent component:

```
<template>
    <v-btn v-on:click="dialog = !dialog">
    </v-btn>
</template
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
           dialog: false
        }
</script
```

Child component:

```
<template>
    <v-layout>
        <v-dialog v-model="toggledialog">
            <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" 
            @click.native="toggledialog = false">Close</v-btn>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-layout>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            toggledialog: false,
        }),
        watch: {
            dialog: function(){
                this.toggledialog = true
            },
        },
        props:['dialog']
}
</script>
```

This code works but I really don't like this workaround with `watch`.

Questions:

1. How to open dialog in child component when `v-model="toggledialog"` if it doesn't watch for `props:['dialog']`?
2. How to change `dialog` to `false` in parent component when I i change it in child component `v-model="dialog"` if in Vue JS it is not allowed to change props?

Comment: There seems to be no examples on the [docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#usage) of using `v-dialog` in separate component, but this question [Open a Vuetify dialog from a component template in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035310/open-a-vuetify-dialog-from-a-component-template-in-vuejs) has two methods.

Comment: Use a Vue global event bus ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a Vuetify dialog from a component template in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035310/open-a-vuetify-dialog-from-a-component-template-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 4):

Pass `value` prop as `value` to `v-dialog`, and re-emit input `v-dialog` whenever you want to close it:

```
//CustomDialog.vue
<v-dialog :value="value" @input="$emit('input')">
    <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" 
        @click.native="$emit('input')"
    >Close</v-btn>
</v-dialog>
...
props:['value']
```

and add v-model to your parent

```
//Parent.vue
<custom-dialog v-model="dialog">
```

So no  `data` and no `watch`

[example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZWRJY)