# VueJS change v-model variable from child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to change the `v-model` of a component by the parent component most I'm not getting.

In the parent component I have a `showProgress` variable, I want it when I change it to `true` the child `v-model` `<progress-modal>` switch to `true`.

**ProgressModal.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="show" persistent max-width="400">
        <v-card :dark="($theme === 'dark')">
            <v-card-title class="headline" v-text="title"></v-card-title>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <div class="text-xs-center mt-2">
                <v-progress-circular indeterminate :size="100" :color="$color"></v-progress-circular>
                <v-card-text v-text="text"></v-card-text>
            </div>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'progress-modal',
        props: ['title', 'text'],
        data: () => ({
            show: true
        }),
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

I already tried to use

```
<progress-modal v-model="showProgress">
```

Instead of `v-model` in `v-dialog` but it does not work :(

Comment: If `showProgress` exists in the parent component, then you cannot use `v-model` (unless you make some fairly advanced changes). Instead, you would need to use a `prop`, and `$emit` any changes back to the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable usage of `v-model` by the parent, you have to define a `value` prop in the child and use it.

```html
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="value" persistent max-width="400">

...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'progress-modal',
        props: ['title', 'text', 'value'], // added 'value'
        data: () => ({
...
</script>
```

This way, when you use:

```html
<progress-modal v-model="showProgress">
```

...the `value` inside `progress-modal` will have the value of parent's `showProgress`.

## Keeping it named `show`

To use other internal name instead of `value` you can [**declare the `model` option**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) in the component.

```html
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="show" persistent max-width="400">

...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'progress-modal',
        props: ['title', 'text', 'show'],    // added 'show'
        model: {                             // added model option
          prop: 'show'                       //
        },                                   //
        data: () => ({
        }),                                  // in this case, remove show from data
...
</script>
```

Comment: Will this not mutate prop (i.e. you are getting error wrt mutating prop)? I didn't test with most recent vue version, but I think practice in `vuejs2` is to emit value to the parent?

Comment: @Traxo It would if dialog was an input or something. The thing is `<dialog>` does not change the `value`, so no problem.

Comment: @acdcjunior ah you are correct, I didn't notice `persistent` option. Without it `v-dialog` should change the `value` when clicking outside, so I think your example wouldn't work properly in that case.

Comment: This works; However, this will get you a "[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly"-message :-(

Answer (score 3):

Pass `value` prop as `value` to `v-dialog` component, and re-emit input from `v-dialog` component:

```
//CustomDialog.vue
<v-dialog :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)">

</v-dialog>
...
props:['value']
```

and add v-model to your parent (custom dialog)

```
//Parent.vue
<custom-dialog v-model="showProgress">
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/geMBJb)

Comment: Nice! In contrast to the accepted solution, this also works with non-persistent dialogs.

Comment: This should be the preferred solution.