# Refactoring vue single file components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

As my single file component is getting bigger, I attempted to refactor it a bit. Turns out I have a couple of dialogs that make the `.vue` file huge (800 lines+). So in order to keep the component clean, I am trying to turn the dialogs into dedicated child components (`mydialog`). I am using vuetify (familiarity with vuetify is not required).

I have a button in the parent component which enables the dialog. I am sending the `dialog` prop to the child component which then gets attached to the `v-model` of the dialog. The problem is, **it only works the first time**. And that's because as I click the `close` button, it changes the `dialog`'s value to `false` and it remains `false` forever because the child component has lost communication with the parent. Under such circumstances, how can I fix this?

Here is the snippet:

```js
Vue.component('mydialog', {
  props:{
    dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },

  template: `
<div class="text-xs-center">
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      width="500"
    >

      <v-card>
        <v-card-title
          class="headline grey lighten-2"
          primary-title
        >
          A Dialog
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        </v-card-text>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            flat
            @click="dialog = false"
          >
            Close
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      // dialog: false,
    }
  }

});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dialog: false
  }

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.2.0/vuetify.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-btn color="red lighten-2" dark @click="dialog=true">Click Me</v-btn>
      <mydialog :dialog="dialog"></mydialog>
    </v-app>

  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.2.0/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035310/open-a-vuetify-dialog-from-a-component-template-in-vuejs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component communication was a bit off: basically your dialog did not inform the app component that it was closed. The following two changes enable the upstream communication between modal and app:

In `app` template:

```
  <mydialog :dialog.sync="dialog"></mydialog>
```

In `mydialog` controller:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      dialog$: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onClose() {
      this.dialog$ = false;
      this.$emit('update:dialog', this.dialog$);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    dialog: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        this.dialog$ = this.dialog;
      },
    },
  }
```

The first change makes the `app` component listen to updates on the `dialog` props of `mydialog`.

In `mydialog` I added a data property `dialog$` which reflects the `dialog` props (because props are considered constant and should not be changed). A watcher takes care that downstream updates on `dialog` update `dialog$`. The `onClose` method updates `dialog$` when the dialog was closed and emits an update to subscribers (specifically `app`).

```js
Vue.component('mydialog', {
  props:{
    dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },

  template: `
<div class="text-xs-center">
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog$"
      width="500"
    >

      <v-card>
        <v-card-title
          class="headline grey lighten-2"
          primary-title
        >
          A Dialog
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        </v-card-text>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            flat
            @click="onClose"
          >
            Close
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      dialog$: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onClose() {
      this.dialog$ = false;
      this.$emit('update:dialog', this.dialog$);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    dialog: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        this.dialog$ = this.dialog;
      },
    },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dialog: false
  },
  template: `
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-btn color="red lighten-2" dark @click="dialog=true">Click Me</v-btn>
      <mydialog :dialog.sync="dialog"></mydialog>
    </v-app>
  `,

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.2.0/vuetify.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.2.0/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

As @raina77ow has mentioned, you can also solve this kind of issue with an [event bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035310/open-a-vuetify-dialog-from-a-component-template-in-vuejs) but it's not necessary in this case.