# How to open vuetify dialog after user logs in to application

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my application I want to show a modal to introduce the user in my application, so it will appear only in the first time he logs in. What I am doing is storing `isNewUser` in the global state and using it to know if it should render the modal or not using the same process described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119008/7373121). (I'm not using event bus)

**Here is my parent component:**

```
<template>
  <Intro :value="isNewUser" @input="finishTutorial" />
</template>

mounted() {
  const store = this.$store;
  this.isNewUser = store.state.auth.user.isNewUser;
},
```

When the user logs in and this component is rendered I saw the dialog being rendered and closing. If I hit f5 it reloads the page and dialog is showed correctly.

If I do the bellow modification it works, but I don't want to solve the problem this way since it won't work for all cases, it will depend on the speed of the user computer/internet.

```
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const store = this.$store;
    this.isNewUser = store.state.auth.user.isNewUser;
  }, 2000);
},
```

**I've tried using v-if as well**

```
<template>
    <Intro v-if="isNewUser" :value="true" @input="finishTutorial" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
    Intro,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isNewUser: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const store = this.$store;
    this.isNewUser = store.state.auth.user.isNewUser;
  },
  methods: {
    async finishTutorial() {
      this.$store.dispatch('auth/finishTutorial');
      this.isNewUser = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: How about using v-if to render the child component only after the value of isNewUser is set?

Comment: I've already tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code for the same? or just do a console.log in the mounted hook of the child component so as to see whether you're getting the right value or not.

Comment: I've edited my question with the code using v-if

Comment: where are you setting the value of isNewUser to true?

Comment: Here:     this.isNewUser = store.state.auth.user.isNewUser;
I've added console.log(this.isNewUser) after this line and it's true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204442/discussion-between-himanshu-and-b-almeida).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed property to do so:

```
computed: {
  isNewUser() {
     return this.$store.state.auth.user.isNewUser;
  }
}
```

and in the template you would do like so:

```
<template>
  <Intro :value="isNewUser" @input="finishTutorial" />
</template>
```

Comment: But i'm not using the computed property because I want to show the dialog only after the component renders. If I use the computed property as you've said the dialog open and closes fast before the component is fully rendered in the screen.

Comment: You should follow @Himanshu tip then because I'm not fully understanding what do you mean