# Vue.js “Maximum call stack size exceeded” error. Use dialog for child and passing data from parent to child failing

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vuetify.js

I am working on Vuetify.js and I am a newbie in Vue, I referred this document [Vuetify Dialogs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/) for creating dialog and solution of Matheus Dal'Pizzol from this link [Open a Vuetify dialog from a component template in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035310/open-a-vuetify-dialog-from-a-component-template-in-vuejs)
 to separate it to the component.
The result I have child component as dialog as below

**Parent**

```html
    <template>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row dense>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-btn large color="success">Add product</v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="3" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
            <v-card class="mx-auto" outlined>
              <v-list-item three-line>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1">{{product.name}}</v-list-item-title>
                  <v-list-item-subtitle>{{product.title}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn dark color="cyan" @click.stop="showScheduleForm = true">
                  <v-icon dark>mdi-television</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn color="primary">Detail</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
            <modal-detail v-model="showScheduleForm" :productDetailInfo="product"></modal-detail>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </template>

    <script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import ModalDetail from "./ModalDetail.vue";
    export default {
      name: "HelloWorld",
      components: {
        ModalDetail
      },
      data: function() {
        return {
          showScheduleForm: false,
          products: [],
          errors: []
        };
      },
    ...
```

**Child**

```html
    <template>
      <v-dialog v-model="show" max-width="500" v-if="Object.keys(productDetailInfo).length !== 0">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2" primary-title>{{ productDetailInfo.name }}</v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>{{ productDetailInfo.title }}</v-card-text>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click.stop="show = false">Close</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="primary">Detail</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "ModalDetail",
      props: {
        productDetailInfo: {
          type: Object
        },
        value: Boolean
      },
      computed: {
        show: {
          get() {
            return this.value;
          },
          set(value) {
            this.$emit("input", value);
          }
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

However, I am getting an exception when I click `icon-button` "Maximum call stack size exceeded".
It seems there is a continuous loop happening.
Please help! Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

That's because your `v-dialog` is in `v-for` loop, it's common [problem](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6892). To workaround it add `:retain-focus="false"` as a prop to your `v-dialog`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to use `v-on:click.stop` instead of `@click.stop` in the `v-btn` as it's the recommended syntax for Vue 2.x.