# Maximum call stack size exceeded Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am Using Vuetify Dialog And this is My code

```
<v-dialog  max-width="390" persistent  v-model="dialog">
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn icon v-if="el.items_count == 0" v-on="on" >
        <v-icon>
          mdi-plus
        </v-icon>
      </v-btn>
  </template>
  <v-card flat>
    <v-card-title>
      this is Son for {{el.title}}
    </v-card-title>
    <v-text-field class="d-block pa-2" v-model="name" outlined label="Name"></v-text-field>
    <v-card-actions>

      <v-btn @click="add" class="d-block">
        <span>Add</span>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="dialog=false" class="d-block">
        <span>Close</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

and this dialog inside loop and get this error after clicking button

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
at VueComponent.onFocusin (VDialog.ts?d213:238)
```

can any one Help me with that error

Comment: I think the problem may be caused by the `v-if` attribute in your dialog activator slot. Try removing that and see if it fixes it. If you want to hide the dialog button, maybe try moving the `v-if` to the dialog itself, i.e. `<v-dialog v-if="..." ...>`

Comment: There is a work around for v-dialog inside loop.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62018919/12185738)

Comment: Anyone wrestling with this, beware of this possibility: Check for identical-names-of-anything (!), file name or instance name. I had a "Keyboard.vue" and another "Keyboard.vue" elsewhere. In code, they occurred in _different_ parent SFC's, however at runtime somehow they collided because of dynamically passing content via slots. I conservatively named everything different; was not able to pin-point the specific culprit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just had the same error. Moving the dialog outside of my loop fixed the problem. 
You have to handle opening and closing your dialog yourself:

```
<v-dialog v-model="open"> ... </v-dialog>
<... v-for="thing in things">
    <v-btn @click="open = true"> ... </v-btn>
</...>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    open: false
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue as well. Can I ask why this is the case?

Answer (score 46):

Setting `:retain-focus="false"` on v-dialog helps too.

Answer (score 5):

This will help you too

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="900px" persistent :retain-focus="false">
 ...
</v-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

on Nuxt adding `<client-only>`  enclosing the element solved the problem