# vuejs v-model value is not updating in parent?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, v-model

**Using Vue3**

**Parent component**

```
<template>
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-12">
        <input-image v-model="imageFile"/>                                                            
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import InputImage from "@/Pages/components/InputImage";
export default{
   components : {
       InputImage,
   },
    
   data() {
       return {
          imageFile : null,
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

**InputImage (child) component**

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div
            class="base-image-input"
            :style="{ 'background-image': `url(${imageData})` }"
            @click="chooseImage"
        >
            <span v-if="!imageData" class="placeholder">Featured Image </span>
            <input
            class="file-input"
            ref="fileInput"
            type="file"
            @input="onSelectFile"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imageData: null,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    chooseImage() {
      this.$refs.fileInput.click();
    },

    onSelectFile() {
      const input = this.$refs.fileInput;
      const files = input.files;
      if (files && files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          this.imageData = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        this.$emit("input", files[0]);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

After selecting the file v-model (*imageFile*) value does not change in parent component why? Even I'm emitting input event to parent component in onSelectFile() method. I'm setting the file name here programmatically. Value changes in child component but file name is not reflected in parent component which I want as through the v-model in parent component.

Answer (score 9):

## Vue 3 changed the events for v-model updates!

Nothing major, but you define your model prop as `modelValue` instead of `model`, and your event as `update:modelValue` instead of input.

So, in your case, just update the child component's method from

```
this.$emit("input", files[0]);
```

to

```
this.$emit("update:modelValue", files[0]);
```

and you should be solid!
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html

Comment: I didn't notice that this was a v3 question. You're right. Thanks for pointing it out.